# Mix WinForms and WinAPI controls

Tags: winforms, winapi, c++-cli

Is it possible to mix WinAPI control creation and WinForms functionality?

Such a code won't work.

```
HWND hWndButton = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
    "BUTTON",
    "OK",
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
    50,
    220,
    100,
    24,
    (HWND)Handle.ToInt32(),
    (HMENU)101,
    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    NULL);
System::Windows::Forms::Control^ control =
    System::Windows::Forms::Control::FromHandle(System::IntPtr(hWndButton));
Controls->Add(control);
```

I need to do this in order to add in a WinForms application some C++ Win32 API written controls by other company.

thx

Comment: Hello, see this article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12563/Hosting-of-MFC-MDI-Applications-from-Within-WinFor) maybe help you.

Comment: Sure, the CreateWindowEx() call works just fine.  But you can't wrap it with Control, FromHandle() is going to return nullptr.  Getting notification messages from the button requires overriding WndProc().  What *exactly* is required to use those 3rd party controls is very unclear, nobody ever does this.  You should of course ask them.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `CreateParams` property from `Control` class to specify desired class name. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2004/11/24/269416.aspx) blog post for detailed explanations.